# Please help me to get my original account

Tags: google-account, account-recovery

I was trying to re-do recover my Gmail account; I now have two Gmail accounts. I'd really like my first original one back, as I have business cards using the first Gmail account. Can you help me on if there's a way to fix this issue?

Answer (score -2):

did u put your mobile number in there? then u can accesses when u are trying to log gmail it ask forget password give it and google sent you a code to your phone.type that code correctly relevant place on your gmail.

https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/gmail/MkewSBfa7DM